# How to resolve errors with the configuration of task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'?

Tags: android, compiler-errors, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm trying to build Android app in Kotlin using dataBinding and when I'm trying to compile this code

```
@Bindable
var progress:Int=1

@NotNull
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "progress")
 fun  SeekBar.getProgress():Int{
    return this.progress
}

@BindingAdapter(value = ["progressAttrChanged"])
fun setListeners(seekBar: SeekBar,inverseBindingListener: InverseBindingListener){
    var listener=object: SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, Progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            progress=Progress
            mBeatBox.mRange=progress/66.67 as Float
            inverseBindingListener.onChange()
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {

        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {

        }
    }
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(listener)
}
```

I get this errors https://ibb.co/cBHRwx.

Here is view of  modelView

```
 <data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.bignerdranch.android.beatboxkotlin.Models.BeatBoxViewModel"/>
</data>
....
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:text="progres"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="9"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        app:progress="@={viewModel.progress}"/>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please post your error in text, not an external image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this error in this way

Updated viewModel
`

```
var progress:Int=mBeatBox.mRange.toInt()
@Bindable set(value){field=value;notifyChange()}
@Bindable get()=field

fun getEditListener():SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
var listener=object: SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, Progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            progress=Progress
            mBeatBox.mRange=(progress/66.67).toFloat()
        }
        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        }
        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        }
    }
    return listener
}`
```

And View looks like:

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:text="progress"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:text="@{String.valueOf(viewModel.progress)}"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        app:OnSeekBarChangeListener="@{viewModel.EditListener}"/>
```

Comment: Mark your answer as solution to close the question please :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your error is pointing to, but looks like there's already a `SeekbarBindingAdapter` defined in the library, so you probably don't need to define your own. If you want to update things when `progress` changes, override `set` or use `ObservableInt` with an `OnPropertyChangedCallback`

Comment: I have just solved my problem in other way but thank you for suggestions.